# How to force on Task from firestore to wait for updated from RoomDB

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, roomdb

Structure of my app looks like that if needed there will be updated from firestore to roomDB. What my problem is that I don't know how to force waiting for firestore Task to wait for new data from roomDB. Here is my case:

```
public LiveData<List<TimeModel>> getAllTimeModelsForAdminSQL(String userId) {

    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<TimeModel> value = timeModelDAO.getAllTimeModelsList(userId);
            collectionReferenceTime.whereEqualTo("id", userId).whereGreaterThan("timestamp", countMethod(value))
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                                List<TimeModel> timeModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot timeModels : queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                                    TimeModel timeModel = timeModels.toObject(TimeModel.class);

                                    timeModelArrayList.add(timeModel);
                                    Collections.sort(timeModelArrayList, new Comparator<TimeModel>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(TimeModel o1, TimeModel o2) {
                                            return o1.getTimeAdded().compareTo(o2.getTimeAdded());
                                        }
                                    });
    
                                }

                                saveAllCollectionToSQLite(timeModelArrayList);
                                updateDataSQLite(timeModelArrayList);
                        
                                collectionReferenceUser.whereEqualTo("userId", userId).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot users : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void run() {
                                                        User user = users.toObject(User.class);
                                                        long hoursToSettle = user.getHoursOverall();
                                                        long timeModelSumForTimeOverall = sumUp(timeModelDAO.getAllTimeModelsList(userId));

                                                        if (hoursToSettle != timeModelSumForTimeOverall) {
                                                        
                                                            timeModelDAO.deleteListForTimeModel(userId);
                                                            getDataFirebase(userId, new Timestamp(new Date(0)));
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
    return timeModelDAO.getAllTimeModels(userId);
}
```

So from first `Task` I need to `saveAllCollectionToSQLite(timeModelArrayList)` or
`updateDataSQLite(timeModelArrayList)`, then in second task I download `timeModelDAO.getAllTimeModelsList(userId)`, but sometimes save or updated don't finished their work from first task and already `timeModelDAO.getAllTimeModelsList(userId)` is invoked.

What I want is that full save or full updated and then app can download data. I thought about RXJava3, but maybe there is simplest solution.